Update installed version of python
I installed python 3.9.6 few years ago on my MacBook, I do not recollect how it was installed (homebrew was not used). Here is version/path info:
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ python3 -V
Python 3.9.6


How to update this python version to the latest?
How to tell how it was installed in the first place?


/usr/bin/python3 indicates that it might be a system standard python. Having said that you could install Python either manually or using conda or using pyenv. After that update the path variable to point to the python that you want to be picked up first.
PS: Pyenv is my favorite with brew being second favorite :).

If the path to the Python executable is /usr/bin/python3 then it was installed with Xcode Command Line Tools. This is an alias to the actual location, check if you have this /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/binDon't update or remove Python with Xcode Command Line Tools, this Python is used by the system.You should use virtual environments to run multiple Python versions. For that you have tools like Pyenv or Rye.

you can run in the terminal which python3 to find the dir where python installed this way you will know the package manager that was used to install python by the category then use the same package manager to update the version.
Hope this Helps :)

they show the output of which python3 in their question. maybe you can elaborate
